# How to inflate a LinearLayout ( for android keyboard )?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an android keyboard, right now I want it just to inflate, i.e. show, linearlayout from main.xml

Here's the java file

```
package keyboard.rob.com;

import ...

public class zyz extends InputMethodService 
implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private KeyboardView mInputView;

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override public View onCreateInputView() {
        mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        return mInputView;
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/LL_whole" android:orientation="vertical" android:clickable="false">


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="@layout/backrep" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/LL_total" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/spell_frame" android:layout_marginBottom="10px" android:layout_marginTop="5px" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/LL_spell" android:paddingLeft="10px">
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/LLrow1">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/LLrow2"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/LLrow3"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/LLrow4">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and the error it crashes with:

```
08-29 20:21:28.128: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10227): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try below code..

```
package keyboard.rob.com;

import ...

public class TotalKeyboard extends InputMethodService 
implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private LinearLayout mInputView;

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override public View onCreateInputView() {
        mInputView = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        return mInputView;
    }
}
```

Comment: @NiranjPatel Can we use the LIstview/Recyclview inside the custom keyboard..Plz help..Plz provide me some link/resource for it ..Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You're casting your layout, which basically is a `LinearLayout`, to a `KeyboardView`. This gives you a classcast exception. Since `onCreateInputView()` returns a `View`, it should suffice to remove the cast. `LayoutInflater.inflate()` already returns a `View`. No need to cast it to anything. *(`LinearLayout` extends the `View` class, so it's valid in this case)*

So try changing

```
mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
```

to

```
mInputView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
```

Alternatively you can cast it to a `LinearLayout`, but thats unneccesary here.